# Can I create a cost function for dot product of two vectors equals to one

Tags: math, optimization, deep-learning

I have two vectors x and y, each has a size of 256 x 1, The results of the dot product of those two vectors is constant and equals to 1.  Which means that x*y' = 1.

Those vectors are affected by any noise, and I need to create a cost function of x*y'= 1 and then optimize it. Is that possible? how can I optimize that cost function?

Thank you

Comment: Of course it is possible. Since you tagged "deep-learning", this is perfectly doable with backpropagation. Your cost function might be (x*y' - 1)^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "cost" to represent how far the dot product `x.y` is from `1`. A simple differentiable cost function would be the squared difference between the dot product and `1`:

```py
def dot_product(x, y):
  return sum(a * b for a,b in zip(x,y))
def cost(x, y):
  return (dot_product(x, y) - 1)**2
```

If you want to implement gradient descent to get a low-cost `x,y` starting from your noisy `x,y`, you need to write a formula for the gradient of the `cost` function. You can do that by hand if you are comfortable with this kind of calculations; or you can rely on a tool like `pytorch` which implements automatic differentiation.

```py
def cost_gradient(x, y):
  k = 2 * (dot_product(x, y) - 1)
  dx = (k * yi for yi in y)
  dy = (k * xi for xi in x)
  return (dx, dy)
```

Then you can write a simple loop; at every iteration, *nudge* `x` and `y` by a very small amount in the opposite direction of the gradient of the loss function. The new vectors `x` and `y` will have a slightly lower cost than the previous vectors, meaning their dot product will be slightly closer to `1`.

```py
def nudge(xy, gradient, learning_rate):
  x,y = xy
  dx,dy = gradient
  x = [xi - learning_rate * dxi for xi,dxi in zip(x,dx)]
  y = [yi - learning_rate * dyi for yi,dyi in zip(y,dy)]
  return (x,y)
```

Finally we can test in the python REPL. I generated random vectors `x` and `y` with 256 coordinates, then I divided every coordinate of `y` by the dot product of `x` and `y`.

```py
>>> dot_product(x,y)
1.0
>>> x = [xi + random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for xi in x]  # add noise
>>> y = [yi + random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for yi in y]  # add noise
>>> dot_product(x, y)
0.8757084508696101
>>> for n in range(100):
...   x,y = nudge((x,y), cost_gradient(x,y), 0.001)
... 
>>> dot_product(x,y)
0.9999999992383757
```

I suggest reading a tutorial on gradient descend with pytorch!

Comment: Thank you so much ,,,  Is it possible to give me the way of doing that in MATLAB instead of paython. I mean the same thing but in MATLAB if possible.

Comment: I haven't used Matlab in many years. It shouldn't be too hard to translate the code. Matlab already implements dot product, so you don't need to write your own function like I did, and Matlab handles a lot of "coordinate-wise" operations, so instead of python's `x = [xi - learning_rate * dxi for xi,dxi in zip(x,dx)]` you can probably write something much simpler like `x = x - learning_rate * dx`.

Comment: OK .. thank you so much, I got it.  What's about if the cost function is |x|-|y| = 0; where |x| is the absolute value of vector x.  Can we use that as a cost function too?

Comment: A little bit of vocabulary: `|x|` is the **norm** of vector x. If you want to perform gradient descent, then the cost function must be differentiable. As a good rule of thumb, if an expression uses the symbol `| |`, then it is not differentiable. Instead, we use squares, which are differentiable; this is why I suggested using `(x.y - 1)^2` and not `|x.y - 1|`.

Comment: @Gze so instead of `|x|-|y|` you can use `x.x - y.y`. This is easily differentiable; but note that if you use this as the cost function, then gradient descent will help you find two vectors `x` and `y` such that `|x| = |y|`, which is completely unrelated to the `x.y = 1` which you originally asked about.

Comment: Finally, please note that something with the sign `=` in it is not a function, but an **equation** or **equality**. Gradient descent is an algorithm whose purpose is to minimize a **function**. If you are trying to achieve a situation where a certain quantity `A` must equal a quantity `B`, we try to minimize the squared difference `(A - B)^2` using gradient descent. The logic is: if `A - B` is close to 0, then `A` is almost equal to `B`.

Comment: I mean we can use another algorithm different from gradient descent to solve that equation in order to get |x| - |y| = 0.

Comment: I mean that abs(x) = abs(y), and then we solve that equation if possible.

Comment: `|x|` is not the absolute value of vector `x`, it is the **norm** of vector `x`. "Absolute value" only makes sense for a real number. Yes, there are tons of algorithms, you can use whatever algorithm you want. But you need to understand what is going on. "In order to get |x| = |y|" is an extremely vague requirement. I could just give you two vectors `x` and `x` that satisfy `|x| = |y|`, no need to apply an algorithm for that. What's the context? If you have a specific question for a specific contest, please post that question with the context. Otherwise this is all just words in the wind.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's the **norm**. OK thank you so much, I will try to post a question for that issue, thanks again

Comment: I posted it here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70344/minimize-the-difference-between-the-absolute-values-of-vectors    .. If you can help, that will be really appreciated.